# Delta sync logic

Tags: architecture, synchronization

Looking for some high-level logic when performing a delta sync.
We have a system A which reads data from a system B - both are SQL DBs. Transfer of data between A and B can take 10 hours. Objects in system B give a Change Date value which tells us when the object changed

We now need to come up with a logic for delta sync - i.e. only capture objects from B which have changed since the last sync finished.

The current logic we have is something like this:

1) Sync data based on last sync date (change date from System B > Last sync date)

2) Store the date after sync has finished into last sync date

I think this logic doesn't capture any changes which might have happened during the sync itself.

Say the last sync date is 17th November 08:00 and I start a sync based on that time. This finishes at 17th November 20:00 and I store that value. Now, during that 10 hour sync some objects in system B changed with a Changedate of 17th November 16:00. In the next cycle, we will miss those objects since the "new" last sync date will be 17th November 20:00

Any suggestions on a high level logic on how to perform delta syncs?

Thanks

UPDATE: I saw a useful article but not sure what "Capture" means
https://community.boomi.com/docs/DOC-2784#jive_content_id_2_GOOD_Extract_by_Last_Modified_Date

Method #2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, think I got it

1) Store the start date of the sync into a variable (say x)

2) Perform the sync (use the value from step 3 to compare)

3) Store the value of x into permanent storage